# How many ways to put n elements into k sets, plus in each set the elements orders matter?

Tags: combinatorics, set-partition

I tried to generalize the question, but I have a concrete example to help specify the problem.

So let's say there's a group of tourists who like to visit 20 monuments of a city under 4 days. How many different ways can they do this, if they're able to visit all monuments in a day if they want so, and it matters, that on a given day in what order they visit them?

Comment: Are the possibilities: $20$ on day $1$ (and $0$ on other days) and $20$ on day $2$ (and $0$ on other days) the same in this context?

Comment: Yes, if you are thinking the 1 day approach first, then it would be: 20! on that day. But you can choose from 4 days so 4*20! is the answer of the 1 day context.

Comment: You started your comment with "Yes" but then you reason that $20$ on day $1$ is *not* the same as $20$ on day $2$. If it was then the number of possibilities under the extra condition that only one day is used, would be $20!$ and not $4\cdot20!$.

Comment: You are right sir! Sorry for misunderstanding your first comment, also my answer for the day 1 context. Now I'm partly understand the problem better as I've started reading the article mentioned in the answer. Have a nice day!

Comment: Looking at the title of your question I actually asked: *does the order of the $k$ sets matter?* If "yes" then both answers on your question are correct. If "no" then they are not correct. Have a nice day too, of course.

Comment: It matters, so I've accepted the faster one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem reduces to partitioning of n elements into $k$ parts, which is by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))
$$
\binom{n+k-1}{n}.
$$
The order can be imposed by all possible permutations of the $n$ elements. Thus
the final answer is:
$$
n! \binom{n+k-1}{n}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce this to a stars and bars problem, where you have $n$ stars or $n$ monuments and $k$ bars or $k$ days. Then, the ways you could partition your $n$ monuments into $k$ days is ${n + k -1}\choose{k-1}$. 
If you care about the order in which you visit the monuments in any given day, then count the possible ways you can arrange $n$ monuments:  $n!$. By the multiplication rule, you have $n!{{n + k -1}\choose{k-1}}$. That is, you can first decide the order in which to visit monuments, and then decide on which days you want to visit them.